# How to send images inside a multiline text field to a docx file

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, word, microsoft-flow, document-template

I have a multiline text field that is being used to gather all time of information (formated text, tables, images from sharepoint that are pasted here, etc.)

I am using the Flow action to Populate a Microsoft Word Template, and passing the field (in the template i am using the "Plain Text Control" developper option), but i only see the image link...

Is there any other way to do this so that the image can be viewed?

[https://westeurope1-
mediap.svc.ms/transform/thumbnail?provider=spo&inputFormat=png&cs=fFNQTw
&docid=https://ptportugal.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.0/drives/b%21mdeQq
xUYRkya9pSRbFNu1VXOp4l6EIBNn6gaOrZUWFNBqETE855KQp7KAlxM6ItI/items/01CLWJNWS
6AZBLLWGVDZDLFODNVWXSRLEY?version%3DPublished&access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1
QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIwMDAwMDAwMy0wMDAwLTBmZjEtY2UwMC0wMDAw
MDAwMDAwMDAvcHRwb3J0dWdhbC5zaGFyZXBvaW50LmNvbUA5YWNkMmRiZC1hZDk3LTQ3
NjgtOTg1NC01ZTI4ZWM1NWZjNDEiLCJpc3MiOiIwMDAwMDAwMy0wMDAwLTBmZjEtY2UwM
C0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAiLCJuYmYiOiIxNjA3NTE1MjAwIiwiZXhwIjoiMTYwNzUzNjgwMCIsI
mVuZHBvaW50dXJsIjoiOWFnRDFGQUpNK25SWWtrVGxoc0xYd2pGeVgrVGU0anY4U2N3eXN1N
UdWTT0iLCJlbmRwb2ludHVybExlbmd0aCI6IjExNyIsImlzbG9vcGJhY2siOiJUcnVlIiwidmVyIjoiaGFz
aGVkcHJvb2Z0b2tlbiIsInNpdGVpZCI6IllXSTVNR1EzT1RrdE1UZ3hOUzAwWXpRMkxUbGhaall0T1
RRNU1UWmpOVE0yWldRMSIsInNpZ25pbl9zdGF0ZSI6IltcImttc2lcIl0iLCJuYW1laWQiOiIwIy5mf
G1lbWJlcnNoaXB8cnVpLXAtbmFiYWlzQHRlbGVjb20ucHQiLCJuaWkiOiJtaWNyb3NvZnQuc2hhc
mVwb2ludCIsImlzdXNlciI6InRydWUiLCJjYWNoZWtleSI6IjBoLmZ8bWVtYmVyc2hpcHwxMDAzM
2ZmZjgyMjA3NDNmQGxpdmUuY29tIiwidHQiOiIwIiwidXNlUGVyc2lzdGVudENvb2tpZSI6IjMifQ.a
2U1cmlxVGdzSFV1TGNpdHBtVUV6ck4zODdwME5WK3NjbWxqNitVR3RFQT0&encodeFail
ures=1&srcWidth=&srcHeight=&width=963&height=546&action=Acc
ess]

This is the Word template :

[image: DocTemplate]

The field Descricaoacoestimadas was created using "Developper" option,   "Plain Text Content Control" option.

It was inserted inside a "Repeating Section Content Control" (Itemrepeat) since i will have many items of text

In my Flow i use an array to hold the text field information:

[image]

The field "Nome do ficheiro" is a Multiline Text Field (enhanced rich text)

The populate action is as follows:

[image]

[image]

If i use a single line text field (instead of the multiline) i get this information in the word file generated by the flow:

[image]

But if i use a Multiline text field i get this type of information inside the table ("Descrição das ações  tomadas"):

[image]

So i get the link to the image but not its content as expected

Comment: Hi Nuno. can you add a few screenshots for context?

Comment: Hi Denis thanks for posting. I added the screen shots when i edited the question.